# Changing x axis values to whole numbers only in R

Tags: r, plot

I'm plotting a time series of hydrological data. The y axis is water level, and the x is time with only major ticks (years) being shown. The plot comes out perfectly fine in every way EXCEPT I'm getting an additional "x.0" at the end of every year on the x axis label. All year values in the data are whole numbers.

I've tried rounding my axis limits ( xlim=c(round(2013,0)) ) but that didn't help much.

I'm not sure how to produce reproducible data for an example, but this subset of data ends up with the same problem in the plot:
[image]

```
hyd<-^^THOSE DATA^^

hyd<-hyd[order(hyd$year),]

hyd2<-ts(hyd, frequency=12, start=c(2013,1))
hyd3<-hyd2[,3]
plot(hyd3, type="l",pch=20, xlab="",ylab="Mean water level (cm)",
     xlim=c(round(2013,0),round(2015,0)),ylim=c(-75,45), #Note the failed attempt at rounding
     col="black",lwd=2)
```

Here is the plot that this code produced:
[image]

I'd like the x axis to be: 2013   2014   2015. Any help is appreciated. Sorry for the confusing data format.

**UPDATE: Using RuiBarrada's response I got what I needed. Working code:**

```
plot(hydro4, type="l",pch=20, xlab="Year",ylab="Mean water level (cm)",
   xlim=c(2013,2016),ylim=c(-75,45),col="black",lwd=2,xaxt="n")
axis(1,at=2013:2015,labels=2013:2015)
```

Comment: Maybe you could try `plot(hyd3, other args, xaxt = FALSE)`, and then use function `axis(1, at = 2013:2015, labels = 2013:2015)`.

Comment: @RuiBarradas Perfect spot on response. Thanks! Updating the question for future users